# Is it possible to disable Auto Index creation in NEST Elastiscsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is it possible to do the following setting in NEST instead of doing it in the yml file?

`action.auto_create_index:false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`action.auto_create_index:false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation) can only be set in the elasticsearch.yml configuration file; it's not a property that can currently be updated through the REST API.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thank you Russ.